# Best way to pull out a section of a string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pull out a number from a string like so `"item_2445_205"`.  So I need to pull out `"2445"` as the item ID and discard the rest. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: jQuery is a DOM library with some utility methods mixed in. You're not working with the DOM, so it's rendered nearly useless here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use some javascript regexes.

```
var string = "item_2445_292"
var matches = string.match(/item_(\d+)_.*/)
var id = matches[1]
```

Comment: Was about to post a version of the same. This is not a problem for Jquery, it is a problem for regular expressions. Docs for the Reg ex object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6e2eb7w(v=VS.85).aspx Docs for the syntax: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1400241x(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

There's more than one way to skin a cat and assuming its coded exactly as in your question, you can use split():

```
var str = 'item_2455_205';
str = str.split('_')[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split it and get an item like this

```
var itemId = "item_2445_205".toString().split('_')[1];
```

this will return item id

Comment: why would you call `toString()` on a string?

Comment: probably he is trying to get "item_2445_205" from another source, its not fixed string, so toString doesnt harm.

Answer (score 1):

The `split()` method comes with all strings:

```
var str = "item_2445_205";
alert(str.split("_")[1]);
//-> 2445
```

or `slice()`, `substring()` or `substr()`:

```
alert(str.slice(5, -4));
//-> 2445

alert(str.substring(5, str.lastIndexOf("_")));
//-> 2445
```

- [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)
- [substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)
- [substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need jQuery for this. Just use plain JS.

For example using `.split()`

```
var string= 'item_2445_205';
var result = myString.split('_');

console.log(result[1]);
```

Or if the amount of characters is always the same using substr